# $_SESSION['id'] doesn't seems to work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, session

I have php page that has jquery ajax call. the begging of this page for sure sets $_SESSION['id'] properly, here is the code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
            header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
    else{
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    }
...?>
```

the ajax call code:

```
   $.ajax({
         url: '../php/functions/user_unused_area_list.php',
         dataType: 'json'        
    }).always(userUnusedAreaList);

  function userUnusedAreaList(list, textStatus, error){
    if(textStatus === 'success'){
        alert(list);
    }
    else {
       alert('Failed: ' + error);
    }
}
```

and here is the pho page which the ajax request calls:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    echo 'good';
}
else{
    echo 'not good';
}
```

I'm getting an alert with Feiled: SyntaxError: UnexpectedToken n. (I think it from "not good") 
**NOTE:** there are other ajax calls and they look the same and they work fine, this one wasted many hours of my life.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `session_start();` at the top of your last code snippet.

Comment: Why because it's worded like a question?  I can change that if it makes you happy. Done..

Comment: Well yes actually. If it's used as a question then it's clear your looking for clarification which should be in a comment, the edited answer is much better.

Comment: I can't believe I have missed this one, Thanks!

Comment: Remember to tick it as correct answer if your problem resolved